# TV videos shown in middle school about reading books, woman book destroyer and a face that hypnotizes kids

Tags: story-identification, tv

When I was in the 7-8th grade (1994), there were class videos we had to watch about this or that. One show in particular had a cliffhanger ending, and I never got to find out what happened.

There were at least two kids. They find a lady who is destroying books aka "I am the book destroyer". The episode in question, had a man whose eyes were closed, then he opens them, hypnotizing one of the kids. It was a live action series, and was as cheesy as it gets...

The video style was similar to a music video called "Ghost of a Chance", where a house trapped a pizza guy who had fractions pop up at points in the song being played about his chances of escaping that particular trap or room (ended with something like 15/16 chance of escape and he picks the one wrong door).

Comment: probably related to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/215683/80s-kids-sci-show-set-in-ny-brownstone-where-inventor-has-invented-teleporting (which seems to be about the series as a whole)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is Episode 9 of Season 2 of *[Read All About It](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read_All_About_It!_(TV_series))* (1979-1981).

> The Book Destroyer traps Lynne and Alex in her mine and says they must help her erase all villains from books.

Found with search terms of *educational videos "book destroyer"*

Comment: how this made it to my classroom in a Kansas city suburb i'll never know